# Jquery autocomplete issue

Tags: java, jquery, ajax, jquery-autocomplete

I am new to jQuery and am trying to use the autocomplete widget with an ajax call to my database.

I am able to call the database, returned ArrayList of string values, and converted the response as a JSON object using `org.codehaus.jackson.map.ObjectMapper` (Do I need to use something else?).

When I put an altar, I can see results as pure strings with comma delimiter, but am not able to see a suggestion list with autocomplete.

Java code that returns the JSON object using `org.codehaus.jackson.map.ObjectMapper`:

```java
response.setContentType("application/json");
response.setHeader("cache-control", "no-cache");  
ArrayList polNo = doa.getPolicyData(ajaxForm.getPolicyNumber());
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();  
OutputStream out = response.getOutputStream();
mapper.writeValue(out, polNo);
```

JavaScript code:

```js
$( "#policyNumber" ).autocomplete({
 source: function (request,response){

 $.ajax({  
 type: "POST",     
 url: "/NB/AjaxSubmit.do",   
  dataType: "json",        
  data: {policyNumber: request.term},

   success: function (data) { 
   alert(data);    
   }

  });  

 },minLength: 3
});
```

alert data showing as : `TMA412732,TMA412733,TMA412734`

---

In above code, I have returned ArrayList of string values and was able to show in autopopulate. I have enhanced the above code to return list of person objects that has first name, last name etc. Now when user typing the firname or last name in the autopopulate , I would like to suggest First name, LastName Middle.

Could someone help to enhance this? Thanks!

success: function(data) {
                        response(data);//u forgot to set data on response
                    }

Comment: You're never passing `data` to the `response` function. What happens if you add `response(data)`?

Answer (score 0):

Change success function like

```
success: function (data) {
response(data); //u forgot to set data on response
```

}

Comment: Thanks for the qucik response. I have not implimented further. I a, just trying to see wha tdata i ma geting back in "data" and it is showing me as "TMA412732,TMA412733,TMA412734". I am looking for next step to show it autocomplete.

Comment: @user2088016: That's what you have to do to show it in the autocomplete.

Comment: Great it is working now :) Thank you all. I wouldl ike to ask on emore question. Assuming if I am passing an array of obejcts(Object containing value and description), i would like to to show description for auto complete but once it is selected, i need to capture it's value just like select box.Any sample code please?

Comment: Hello, In above code, I have returned ArrayList of string values and was able to show in autopopulate. I have enhanced the above code to return list of person objects that has first name, last name etc. Now when user typing the firname or last name in the autopopulate , I would like to suggest First name, LastName Middle.

Could someone help to enhance this?